# To specify Startup Program in Visual C# Express Edition 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, visual-studio-express

I usually do the following at office - 
Set the startup program for the project to System32\dllhost.exe, and set the
command line arguments for the startup program accordingly. 
This used to work perfectly fine, because I was running Visual Studio 2008. However, one of my developers use C# Express Edition and they need to do a similar thing. We are not sure, where to set this or how to do it?

Please suggest how to do this or point us in the right directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSProj file, under the PropertyGroup tag, you will have the following tags. Add the appropriate details, and you should be good to go.

```
<StartAction>Program</StartAction>
<StartArguments>/ProcessId:{C401EBE5-70E8-4AB6-935A-F0589EA01004}</StartArguments>
<StartPage>
</StartPage>
<StartProgram>C:\WINDOWS\system32\dllhost.exe</StartProgram>
<StartURL>
</StartURL>
<StartWorkingDirectory>
</StartWorkingDirectory>
<StartWithIE>true</StartWithIE>
```

How I did it -

1. Looked at each file in my system, which was built with VS2008.
2. In the CSProj file, I had the following details, I copy pasted the same onto the developer's PC and it worked.